# How to get authentication with jwt slim middleware?

Tags: php, slim

This code works, but how can I get the permissions to see the `/api` content with a get request??

```
<?php
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = new \Slim\App();

    $app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
        "path" => "/api", 
        "secret" => "1234"
    ]));

    $app->get('/api', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
      echo "Hi";
    });

    $app->get('/teste', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
      echo "Hi";
    });

    $app->run();
```

Comment: Made the title clearer and language more concise. Please edit the question and provide an example of the output you are getting versus what you are expecting. Thanks!

Comment: sorry i change the title, i was trying to acess the /api with a get request , but i dont know that the key need to be encode with jwt mode and need to be in the header of the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used `Authorization: Bearer Mykey` , the key need to be encode in jwt mode

Answer (score 3):

## 1. Generate Token

Using [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt)

```
$payload = [
    "sub" => "user@example.com"
];
    $token = JWT::encode($payload,'JWT-secret-key');
```

## 2. .htaccess Changes

If using Apache add the following to the .htaccess file. Otherwise PHP wont have access to Authorization: Bearer header

```
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

## 3. Middleware

```
$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => "/api",
    "passthrough" => ["/teste"],
    "secret" => "JWT-secret-key",
    "secure" => false,
    "callback" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) use ($container) {
        $container["jwt"] = $arguments["decoded"];
    },
    "error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "0";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        $data["data"] = "";
        return $response
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
]));
```

## 4. Correct Request

[image]

## 5. Wrong Token Request

[image]

[Reference Link](https://appelsiini.net/projects/slim-jwt-auth/)