# Slim Framework with JWT Authentication and Postman

Tags: jwt, postman, slim

I am using Slim Framework to develop a REST API with JSON Web Token and then test it with Postman. I have created the Database connection, I have tested GET, POST, PUT, DELETE in Postman, everything works fine and now I come to the JWT Authentication. Bear in mind that Basic Http Authentication works fine also. So, code

.htaccess

```
RewriteRule .* - [env=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

customers.php

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;
$container = $app->getContainer();
$container["jwt"] = function ($container) {
    return new StdClass;
};

$app->add(new \Slim\Middleware\JwtAuthentication([
    "path" => "/api",
    "passthrough" => ["/api/token", "/admin/ping"],
    "secure" => true,
    "environment" => "HTTP_X_TOKEN",
    "header" => "X-Token",
    "secret" => "supersecretkeyyoushouldnotcommittogithub",
    "callback" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) use ($container) {
        $container["jwt"] = $arguments["decoded"];
    },
    "error" => function ($request, $response, $arguments) {
        $data["status"] = "error";
        $data["message"] = $arguments["message"];
        return $response
        ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        ->write(json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
    }
]));

$app->add(function($request, $response, $next) {
    $token = $request->getQueryParams()["token"];
    if (false === empty($token)) {
        $request = $request->withHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {$token}");
    }
    return $next($request, $response);
});

//Get All Customers
$app->get('/api/customers', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $customers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($customers);

        $fp = fopen('empdata3.json', 'w');
        fwrite($fp, json_encode($customers));
        fclose($fp);

        header("Location: https://www.pawebgate.com/slimapp3/public/empdata3.json");
        die();
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});

//Get Specific Customer
$app->get('/api/customer/{id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $id = $request->getAttribute('id');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers where id = $id";

    try{
        //Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $customer = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($customer);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

Can you please help me on how to set Postman in order to test the above functionality, or any other steps I have to do in order to achieve JWT Auth?
I always get "Token not found in Postman"
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set the `X-Token` http header in postman? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests#headers

Comment: Hi Daniel O, can you please be a bit more specific, I read your link but could not figure out how to do it. Step by step settings please

Comment: Related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570612/how-to-get-authentication-with-jwt-slim-middleware/55728981#55728981

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to create a route for get the Token, like this:

```
$app->post('/auth/token', function(Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
$data       = $request->getParsedBody();
$email      = $data['email'] ?? null;
$password   = $data['password'] ?? null;

/*[select logic here]*/
$user = $db->query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = $email AND password = $password")...
/*[select logic here]*/

if($user){

    $key = 'supersecretkeyyoushouldnotcommittogithub';
    return $response->withJson([
        'token' => JWT::encode($user, $key)
    ]);
}
    return $response->withJson(['status' => 'error'], 401);
});
```

Then, you can copy the response and make a POST request in Postman, adding the token to a header "Authorization".
[image]